# jquery scroll to not-quite top

Tags: jquery, scroll

I already know about:

```
$(body).animate({scrollTop: $("#id").offset().top}, 'slow');
```

But I have an odd situation where this particular site I'm working on has a fixed header/banner (200px high) that remains in place when the page is scrolled. If I use the above routine, it will literally scroll the element to the top of the window, but the first 200px's worth will be hidden by the header/banner (*I don't like the fixed header/banner, but I am not allowed to change that at this time*).

So, the question is: **How can I scroll to the top-200px so that the element is scrolled to just below the header/banner?**

Thanks in advance for your assistance with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of ways to do this, but won't this be solved by using `$(body).animate({scrollTop: $("#id").offset().top - 200}, 'slow');`?

Comment: I could have sworn I had tried this before and gotten a syntax error - I think that because I had the line wrapped (where "}, 'slow');" was on a separate line) that I might have earlier put a semi-colon after the "200" (not in quotes).  In short: BINGO! - much thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The issue  is that with position:fixed - the header is removed from the page flow and the rest of the page is rendered as if its not there - so scrolling to elements will be out by the same amount as the height of the header.

The solution is that when you set the position of the header to fixed (if it changes on the scroll position) - you also set the padding-top of the body by the height of the header. **If the header is always fixed to the top of the screen and doesn't change based on the scroll portion - then simply apply the padding-top directly to the body.**

Therefore if the header is 200px in height - simply apply

```
 body {padding-top: 200px}
```

when the header has position:fixed applied to it.

**Don't forget to remove that same padding when the header is returned to position:static.** - assuming that there is a scroll position attached to when the sticky class is applied.

The best way to do all this would be to have a class such as header-offset and apply it to the body when you are applying the position:fixed.

so it would be

```
.header-offset{padding-top: 200px; // or whatever height your header is}
```